# Three Column Layout with Two Collapsible Left Navs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

### A Quick Overview

I am currently working on a page that will have three total columns, in order from left to right they are:

- Project List
- Code Details
- Code Window

Now, `Project List` and `Code Details` have a `max-width` each of `600px` but should be `100%` on mobile where the display order would be `Code Details` -> `Project List` -> `Code Window` and all three should fit in the page when on desktop. This has been a tedious task but I'm almost there, I just think I'm missing something.

Also, not that it is entirely relevant to this post, but I'm also using Bootstrap 4 which may or may not impact how the solution is implemented (currently I don't see a reason, but including this just in case).

---

### The Issue

I need the `Project List` and `Code Details` collapsed by default and the `Code Window` should be at full width when both are collapsed. Then if the `Project List` or the `Code Details` are being displayed, the `Code Window` should fill any remaining space to the right. This is similar to how Google used to handle [their maps](https://www.google.com/maps/search/restaurants+near+me/@31.2429185,-85.3807884,15z/data=!3m1!4b1).

I've tried several approaches, and the closest I've been is by creating a single container for the left two columns, and putting `Project List` and `Code Details` in the left container, then the `Code Window` gets a width of `100%`.

I use `float: left` on the left container and both the `Project List` and `Code Details` (which using it on the children may be an issue, but removing it didn't fix the issue), and `width: 100%` on the `Code Widnow`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main-content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.left-content {
  float: left;
}
.right-content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5c7;
}
.project-list {
  max-width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #f33;
}
.code-details {
  max-width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #37f;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="left-content">
    <div class="project-list">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Felis donec et odio pellentesque. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="code-details">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Felis donec et odio pellentesque. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Felis donec et odio pellentesque. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this setup the left columns overlap each other instead of stacking side by side on desktop. I want them overlapping on mobile, but not on desktop. You can clearly see this effect in the example above.

---

### The Question

How do I retain the functionality of *fill remaining width* and prevent overlapping while stacking in `div` elements from the left to display my left side panels on desktop? I can take care of mobile friendly later, but I think I ended up with tunnel vision on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by applying `flex-grow: 1` on the code-window element. If you either collapse project-list, code-details or both code-window will take the remaining space.

With media queries you can remove the `display: flex` and the `max-width: 200px` properties for mobile to make them full width.

```css
.main-content {
    display: flex;
}

.project-list {
    background-color: #FF3333;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.code-details {
    background-color: #3377FF;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.code-window {
    background-color: #55CC77;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="project-list">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Felis donec et odio pellentesque. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.</p>
     </div>

    <div class="code-details">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Felis donec et odio pellentesque. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="code-window">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Felis donec et odio pellentesque. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 3fr;
}

.main-content>div{
    padding: 12px;
}

.project-list {
    background-color: #F33;
}

.code-details {
    background-color: #37F;
}

.code-window {
    background-color: #5C7;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="project-list">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Felis donec et odio pellentesque. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.</p>
     </div>

    <div class="code-details">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Felis donec et odio pellentesque. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="code-window">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque. Quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Felis donec et odio pellentesque. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```